# how do you add a gallery to the homepage without using a post or page?

Tags: themes, gallery, homepage

okay ive been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

im trying to add images directly onto the homepage.
ive created a gallery with a shortcode, and have added the shortcode into a post.
but i dont want the post to display. i just want a bunch of images on my homepage.

ive tried creating a page with the shortcode, but its a url link to the gallery.

can i just directly add the shortcode to the body of the homepage?

for example, if you look at the hitchcock theme on wordpress, it looks like a bunch of images. https://wordpress.org/themes/hitchcock/

how do i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with PHP or from a users standpoint with a plugin or theme? This is a development Stack and it would be much easier to do from a PHP standpoint.

Comment: from a users standpoint with a plugin.

but i am kinda familar with coding as well. i used to do java/python